# Makefile, executable and object files in different directories

Tags: linux, makefile

I'm trying to get the object files and the executable file in different directories. In the root folder there is a obj and exe folder for this, but i have no idea how to get make to run it.

I have tried stuff like:

```
$(EXEDIR)/sfml-app: $(OBJ)
```

and

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
```

but it gives me errors. Can anybody explain me how I can get this to run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your output to go to another directory, you have to tell make (and the compiler) about it.  They won't just guess because you have a variable named `OBJDIR`!  You have to actually make use of it.

Make sure your target names have the directory prefix so make knows where you expect the object files to end up:

```
OBJ = $(patsubst %.cpp, $(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(SRC))
```

and make sure you tell the compiler where you want the object files to end up by using the `-o` flag:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Similarly, if you want the final output to to into `EXEDIR` you have to use it both in the makefile *and* send that value to the linker, again via `-o`:

```
all: $(EXEDIR)/sfml-app

$(EXEDIR)/sfml-app: $(OBJ)
        $(CXX) -o $@ $(OBJ) $(LIBS)
```